# Why axios doesnt return API response when error thrown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, redux-saga

Im using React with redux-saga.

I have  a simple `/GET` request. However, if any error is thrown by API, e.g. `400 bad request`, **Im unable** to get the response returned by my API.

Example - `/getUsers` returns `400 bad request` and a response `"Your form is invalid"`. I can see it in network, that it was **properly** returned. However, in my `try catch`:

```
catch((error) => console.log(error.message))
```

is always a `Network Error`. I dont want to display to user `Network Error`, but the response returned by API.

#### Question:

How can I get correct API response error message?

- request function:

  ```
  const getUsers = () => api.get(URL);
  ```
- axios instance

  ```
  const api = axios.create();
  ```
- saga function (just an example)

  ```
  try {
     yield call(getUsers);
  } catch(error) {
     yield put(getUsersFail(error.message));
  }
  ```

Comment: Have you tried `error.response.data.message`?

Comment: As long as you don't get a `2xx` HTTP response, you'll get to the catch.

Comment: Are you sure that `Network Error` is caused by 400? Usually you would get this error from CORS.

Comment: @Tholle `error.response` doesnt exist unfortunately

Comment: @estus ye, however it really doesnt matter, what matter is that these are XHR errors, not these coming from API :(

Comment: Actually, this matters. I'd suggest to figure out what error you deal with. You stated it's `bad request` in one place and `Network Error` in another. If there's a response, it should be available as `error.response`. There won't be any response in case of CORS error.

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors, there should be something in `error.response` in case there was a response from server

Answer (score 0):

We have to get the response from axios call at first and check it's status. If it's a 400 error throw and catches it.

```
try {
  const response = yield call(api.get, url)

  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    yield put({ type.TYPE, response })
  } else {
    throw response
  }

} catch(error) {
   // API response error message
   yield put({type.TYPE_ERROR, error.message})
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work that way, I mean, catch after `api.get` catches error from saga, not from api

Comment: I added my answer

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: @lucascaro is it better?

Comment: It is! you might want to add a brief explanation on why a 400 error (and others) are not thrown by `call()` even though they are errors (this is a common source of confusion), and maybe even a bit on why you check for `status >= 200 and < 300`

Answer (score 0):

try this please:

```
try {
  const response = yield call(api.get, url)

  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    yield put({ type.TYPE, response })
  } 
  else {
   throw new Error(JSON.stringify(response));
  }
} catch(error) {
    const errorMessage = error.response && error.response.error && error.response.error.message;
    const errorMessage2 = error.request;
    const errorMessage3 = error.message;
    const reportedError = errorMessage || errorMessage2 || errorMessage3;

    yield put({type.TYPE_ERROR, reportedError })
}
```